# The builder for route "/" returned null

Tags: flutter

I defined a non null route for `'/'`, but I still get an error :/
If I provide a `home` parameter to `MaterialApp`, it will work fine.

```
return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: 'My App',
    theme: AppTheme.lightMode,
    darkTheme: AppTheme.darkMode,
    themeMode: themeChanger.getTheme,
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
      '/': (ctx) => LoginPage(),
      '/home': (ctx) => homePage,
      CoursesPage.routeName: (ctx) => CoursesPage(),
      CourseDetailsPage.routeName: (ctx) =>
          CourseDetailsPage(),
      CourseInside.routeName: (ctx) => CourseInside()
    },
  );
```

Comment: Have you created constant file and set all parameters in this file?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede no no.. its all in differnt files

Comment: Actually, your code looks right to me

Comment: '/': (ctx) => homePage,
 '/home': (ctx) => LoginPage(),

try by this and then check